# REACT.js on select disable radio button and check second option

Tags: forms, reactjs, select, radio-button

I have been changing a form based on REACT and this is something I am a newb with (been using it already for 4 months but just segments of it, sometimes actual progress with the programming is based on pure luck and every time on advices of good people found here).

Currently I have a task of re-developing a form of this look:
[image]

What I need to achieve is Calibration radios' behavior based on Type's selection: if argument `calibration` is set to 0 (zero) then disable option 'Accredited' and check second option automatically.

**Edited: 19 Oct 2017**

This creates the drop down, and the DD works great:

```
createSuggestInput(name) {
    const { id, value, labels } = this.props;
    const _t = this.props.intl.formatMessage;

    var options = [
      { value: 'one',   label: 'One',   calibration: '0' },
      { value: 'two',   label: 'Two ',  calibration: '1' },
      { value: 'three', label: 'Three', calibration: '0' },
      { value: 'four',  label: 'Four',  calibration: '1' },
    ];

    return  <Select.Creatable
                     name = {`${id}_${name}`}
                    value = {this.state.brandSelect}
              placeholder = {_t(translations.txtSuggest)}
                  options = {options}
                 onChange = {this._onChange.bind(this)}
                    label = {labels[name]}
                      key = {`${id}_${name}`}
        promptTextCreator = { (label) => _t(translations.txtCreate) + ' ' + label + _t(translations.txtCreateEnter) }
    />;
}
```

When selected option's calibration value is ZERO, I need to update set of Calibration radio buttons, by disabling the option "Accredited" and at the same time checking the second option, "Not Accredited".

```
createRadioCalibration(name) {
    const { id, value, labels } = this.props;
    const _t = this.props.intl.formatMessage;

    const ACCREDITATION_TYPES = [
        [CALIBRATION_ACCREDITED, _t(messages.calibrationAccredited)],
        [CALIBRATION_NOT_ACCREDITED, _t(messages.calibrationNotAccredited)]
    ];

    return  <FormChoiceGroup
                    type = "radio"
                  values = {ACCREDITATION_TYPES.map(mapValueArray)}
                     key = {`${id}_${name}`}
                    name = {`${id}_${name}`}
                   value = {value[name]}
            handleChange = {this.handleFieldChangeFn(name)}
            />;
}
```

These two are rendered as follows:

```
render () {

    const FIELDS = {
        [CALIBRATION]: this.createRadioCalibration(CALIBRATION),
        [TYPE]: this.createSuggestInput(TYPE),
    }; 

    return (
        <div className="repair-form-device repair-form-device-field-row">

            <div className="repair-form-device-id">
                {id + 1}
            </div>

            <div className="clearfix repair-form-device-content">

                <div className="">
                    { FIELDS[TYPE] }
                </div>

                <div className="">
                    <label>{_t(messages.repair)}</label>
                    { FIELDS[CALIBRATION] }
                </div>
.....
```

And lastly the `_onChange` function:

```
_onChange(tool) {
    const { id } = this.props;
    this.setState({
        brandSelect: tool
    });
}
```

As I stated previously, I am stuck with the main task, which is manipulating the Calibration radio buttons.

I believe I can update its status inside the `_onChange` function, but everything I tested so far lead me nowhere.

Your patience is much appreciated!

Comment: You should try to reduce the code here to what represents your problem instead of pasting it all, so that it becomes readable for anyone wanting to help. Isolating the stuff is actually also a good debugging technique.

Comment: I always place minimal code and then I am asked to provide this and this and that. This time I decided to go one step ahead and paste all functions that are related to the problem.

Comment: You did not understand me right. Not removing code from different files that is useful to understand the question, but the 100+ lines that define a <label>, tooltips or whatever does not help at all trying to read it through. Moreover, it is not clear what you want and what is not working. The radio buttons - which we don't see anymore - 's options have a `checked` attribute that can be part of your state, and a `disabled` attribute. So is your problem that the state is not updating correctly?

Comment: What I want to achieve is manipulating the states of Calibraton radio buttons in current loop, based on the `calibration` argument selected in drop down list. If calibration arg is ZERO, disable first radio and select the second one. I guess all the logic can happen in `_onChange` function. In jQuery I would use something like:  __if calibration is zero, radio_one_id.attr('disabled',true); radio_two_id.attr('checked', 'checked')__

Comment: In React, you will use something like `if (calibration === 0) { this.setState({radio_one_checked: true}) }` and then `<input type='radio' checked={this.state.radio_one_checked}>`.

Comment: Even when I used checked argument (and this argument exists in FormChoiceGroup) and theoretically both radios should be selected on default, nothing happens (as per update in the code)

Comment: In what you posted, `checked` is set with state, but that state is never changed. Nothing makes sense as it is, the code is unclear, we cannot see the components hierarchy of props, we cannot even see the class name of the component of interest, it is still cluttered with useless code, and still not properly formatted.

Comment: I tried to paste yet another piece of code to clearly explain the flow and the logic of the form.

Comment: Selecting the radio button while the drop down is affected: `        var ding = ( tool.calibration === '1' ) ? 'calibration_accredited' : 'calibration_not_accredited';
        this.props.handleFieldChange( id, 'calibration', ding );` inside the `_onChange` function